# Neo4j - How do I decide what to index?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

Let's say I've created 50K `Person`s:

```
UNWIND [ ... ] AS name
CREATE (:Person { name: name, joinTimestamp: 1000000 })
```

I need to have these nodes create random relationships between each other:

```
MATCH (p1:Person { joinTimestamp: 1000000 }), (p2:Person { joinTimestamp: 1000000 })
WITH p1, p2, rand() AS random
WHERE random < 0.001 AND p1 <> p2
MERGE (p1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p2)
```

This works, but I'd like to speed up that second query. What should I index? I would assume that Neo4j would use `p1` and `p2`'s ID to locate them during the `MERGE`. Should I index that? Or should I index the `joinTimestamp` property, since it's used in the `MATCH` query? Maybe indexing can't help this query at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the native ID of a node for indexing (since the native ID of a node is not really a "property" of the node). And you would not need to do that anyway, since neo4j can already quickly get to a node by its native ID.

Instead, you can index `:Person(joinTimestamp)`, because `joinTimestamp` *is* a property of `:Person` (and your query can use it at the start).

By the way, you can always use [profiling](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) to verify that an index would be used.

Comment: Would this also impact the `MERGE`? I find that similar queries aren't as slow, it's the relationship creation that slows down my query.

Comment: No, standard indexes would not be able to speed up `MERGE`s that potentially create only relationships (since such indexes are only for nodes).

Comment: Hmm ok, well adding the index did help with the `MATCH` so I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in Neo4j are used to find starting points in the graph, you won't need them for traversals or things like that.

Since you're looking up these nodes by joinTimestamp, it makes sense to index :Person(joinTimestamp). Basically you'd look for the common means you plan to lookup your nodes in your queries (for example, looking up a person node by their name property) and add an index on those.

Comment: As I said to [cybersam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57047930/8961491), would this also impact the `MERGE`?

Comment: I'll echo cybersam here, no, merging of relationships doesn't use indexes. You already have the nodes (looked up from the joinTimestamp index, hopefully) at the point that you're doing the MERGE, so there's nothing more that an index could help with. Just keep in mind that indexes are used to do your initial node lookups, and after you've got your starting nodes, then traversals to connected nodes take care of the rest.